# as3 trouble loading a CSV file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, csv

This is my first project involving external classes in flash, so this may be a fairly basic question:
I'm trying to load a csv file in the class CSVloader:

```
package Application {

import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.net.*;

import Application.*;

public class CSVloader {
    private var waiting = true;
    private var CSVdata:Array;
    private var myCsvLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;
    public function CSVloader() {

    }

    public function loadCSV(Args:String){

        myCsvLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
        myCsvLoader.load(new URLRequest(Args));
        myCsvLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onWait);
        return CSVdata;
    }

    public function onCSVLoaderReady():Array {
            var CSVdata:Array;
            var str:String = myCsvLoader.data as String;

            CSVdata = str.split("\n");

            for (var i:int=0; i<CSVdata.length; i++) {
              CSVdata[i] = CSVdata[i].split(';');
            }

            for(var q:int = 0; q<(CSVdata.length-1);q++){
                CSVdata[q][1] = CSVdata[q][1].slice(0,-1);
            }

            trace("CSV loaded! : " + CSVdata);
            return CSVdata;
    }


    private function onWait(e:Event):void{
        CSVdata = onCSVLoaderReady();
    }

}
```

}

How can I write the CSVloader class so when I call CSVloader("some url") I get an Array with all the data?

This is my AppController class:

```
package{
import Application.CSVloader;
import Application.C;

import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class AppController extends MovieClip{

    public function AppController() {
        // constructor code

    }

    public function init(){
        var myCSVLoader = new CSVloader();
        trace(myCSVLoader.loadCSV("data.csv"));
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really return data from event listeners like you do a normal function, because they are called asynchronously (they are not called right away). What you need to do is dispatch an event from your CSVLoader when the csv data is ready.

CSVLoader needs to extend EventDispatcher so that it can dispatch events. Add this to your imports:

```
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
```

Make CSVLoader extend EventDispatcher and add a class property to hold the csv data:

```
public class CSVLoader extends EventDispatcher {
    public var csvData = [];
    ...
```

in `onCSVDataReady()`, don't create a new array to hold the data, use the property you declared above.
At the end of `onCSVDataReady()`, remove your return statement and add:

```
dispatch(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
```

Don't forget to change the return type in the method declaration to void. You should also remove all the return statements you have right now, because they aren't going to return anything.

Then in AppController do this:

```
private var myCSVLoader = new CSVLoader();

public function init(): void {
    myCSVLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeListener);
    myCSVLoader.loadCSV("data.csv");
}

private function completeListener(evt: Event): void {
    trace(myCSVLoader.csvData);
}
```

Ideally you would make csvData in CSVLoader private and make a getter method to access it, but I did it this way for brevity.